# Error: no line found. ¿A que se debe?

Tags: java, while

Se supone que al entrar al try, luego del scanner imprime por pantalla el la primer linea. Con el while comprobaria si la linea esta null, y deberia continuar. ¿Alguien podria guiarme en que estoy fallando?

```
Public class Testv2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //TreeMap<Integer, String> DatosAlumno = new TreeMap <Integer, String>();
    Establecimiento e= new Establecimiento ();
    
    try {
        Scanner s= new Scanner (new File("alumnos.txt"));
        
        String linea=s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(linea);
        
        while((linea=s.nextLine())!=null) {
            
        String[]datos =linea.split(" ");
        
        Integer numlegajo = Integer.parseInt(datos[0]);
        
        double promedio = ((Double.parseDouble(datos[3]) + Double.parseDouble(datos[4]) + Double.parseDouble(datos[5]))) /3;
        
        Alumno alumno = new Alumno (datos[1],datos[2],promedio);
        
        e.agregarAlumno(numlegajo, alumno);
        
        }
        
        e.DatosLista();
    }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + exception.getMessage());
        }

}
```

}

Comment: Hola amigo, has mirado que el fichero no esté vacio? Porque piensa que no te está leyendo del teclado, sinó del fichero.

Comment: Si lo he mirado ! no era el fichero, gracias !

Comment: De todas maneras, si lo que que quieres es leer de un fichero, hay muchas clases, como FileReader, BuferedReader, RandomAccesFile,etc. Que facilitan mucho la operación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario que verifiques si hay una linea mas antes de llamar al método nextLine().

Lo anterior lo logras modificando la parte de tu codigo que dice `while((linea=s.nextLine())!=null)` por `s.hasNext()` y una vez que validas que si hay siguiente linea entonces puedes acceder al valor mediante `s.nextLine()` ya dentro del ciclo while.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class testLines {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("alumnos.txt"));

            String linea = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(linea);

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                linea = s.nextLine();
                System.out.println(linea);

            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + exception.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hice eso y uno que otro cambio leve, me fue de ayuda. Gracias !